# How to change part of the string using sed?

Tags: sed, sh

I have a file `data.txt` with the following strings:

> > text-common-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
> >
> > text-special-common-2.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
> >
> > some-text-variant-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
> >
> > text-another-variant-text-3.3.3-SNAPSHOT.jar

I want to change all of the `text-something-digits-something.jar` to `text-something-5.0.jar`.

Here is my script with `sed` (GNU sed version 4.2.1
), but it doesn't work, I don't know why:

```
#!/bin/bash
for t in ./data.txt
do
    sed -i "s/\(text-[a-z]*-(\d|\.)*\).*\(.jar\)/\15.0\2/" ${t}
done
```

What is wrong with my `sed` usage?

Comment: I imagine your `sed` doesn't support `\d` for digits.

Comment: What's with the `for` loop if you only have one file?

Comment: @tripleee, one file is just example. In fact this file is the list of files where changes should be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this `awk`

```
awk '/^text/ {sub(/[0-9].*\./,"5.0.")}1'
text-common-5.0.jar
text-special-common-5.0.jar
some-text-variant-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
text-another-variant-text-5.0.jar
```

`text-something-digits-something.jar` to `text-something-5.0.jar`
equal change `digits-someting` to `5.0`
It also takes care of changing line only starting with `text`

Comment: Hm. It seems to work, but is it possible to make changes in place?

Comment: Yes, do like this: `awk '/^text/ {sub(/[0-9].*\./,"5.0.")}1' file > tmp & mv tmp file`. It would emulate the `-i` for `sed`

Answer (score 0):

I think a simpler approach might be enough: `sed -r -e 's/(text-(.*-)?common-)([0-9\.]+)(-.*\.jar)/\15.0\4/' < your_data`.

Another way of saying the same thing with perl: `perl -pe 's/(text-(?:(.*-))*common-)([\d\.]+)(-.*\.jar)/${1}1.5${4}/' < your_data`.

Comment: I don't need to change `some-text-variant-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`. This is a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
sed '/^text-/ s/-[0-9.]*-/-5.0-/' file
```

Comment: This will also change version of `some-text-variant-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
for t in ./data.txt
do
    sed -i '/^text-/ s/[.0-9]\{1,\}-something\(\.jar\)$/5.0\2/' ${t}

    # for "any" something
    #sed -i '/^text-/ s/[.0-9]\{1,\}-[^?]\{1,\}\(\.jar\)$/5.0\2/' ${t}
done
```

select string starting with text and change digit value is present